# how to insert text to date field in oracle

Tags: oracle

how to insert (text) time: `09:44:02`  and  date:`11/09/2007`  to  date filed in Oracle ?

i have field Tdate (date)  and Ttime (date)  in oracle

thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

Since a date is a point in time you should really only use one field:

```
insert into your_table (dt) 
   values (to_date ('11/09/2007 09:44:02', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'));
```

Since your model contains two columns, you could use:

```
insert into your_table (Tdate, Ttime)
   values (to_date('11/09/2007', 'dd/mm/yyyy'),
           to_date ('09:44:02', 'hh24:mi:ss'));
```

Note however that by default your `Ttime` column will contain date information which may be false/irrelevant since you can not store only the time component:

```
SQL> select to_char(tdate), to_char(ttime) from your_table;

TO_CHAR(TDATE)      TO_CHAR(TTIME)
------------------- -------------------
11/09/2007 00:00:00 01/08/2011 09:44:02
```

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO <table>
(date_column)
VALUES
(TO_DATE(tdate||' '||ttime, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'))
/
```

If it is in PL/SQL

```
DECLARE
   v_date_field DATE;
BEGIN
   v_date_field := TO_DATE(tdate||' '||ttime, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS');
   --
   INSERT INTO <table>
   (date_column)
   VALUES
   (v_date_field);
END;
/
```

Don't forget to commit afterwards :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into tablename(tdate) 
values(to_date('11/09/2007 09:44:02','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'))
```